# DisplayLink v1.10 - LaunchDaemon?

Tags: launchd, ventura

I recently upgraded to Ventura from Catalina and I use DisplayLink for an external monitor.  I have a script that took care of stopping and starting the DisplayLink daemon and user agent services on sleep/wake as I had found the software would get wonky when running for longer periods.

Since upgrading I also installed the latest driver (v1.10) from the synaptics website... but I notice that the LaunchDaemons and LaunchAgents are gone.  I found that opening the 'DisplayLink Manager.app' bundle starts the user agent and restores functionality for me, but how is this supposed to work on startup?  I also don't find that the 'DisplayLink Manager.app' is listed in my login items...

Anyone know how this is supposed to work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps someone... but I figured out the answer.  So the app only runs in the user context now by default when installed.  After starting the 'DisplayLink Manager.app' it puts an icon in your menubar. You can click that icon to download a separate pre-login application that you install to provide the external display login prompt. Additionally, you have to select a box that starts the 'DisplayLink Manager.app' at login... else you have to manually start the app.

Not sure on why these design decisions were made, but this is really strange and not at all end-user friendly.